# Web audio API and multiple inputs mic device

Tags: audio, web-audio-api

I have an audio device with 4 inputs microphones..

Does anyone knows if I can use all these inputs with Web audio API?

Comment: From my understanding there is no support for this in the WebAudio Spec yet.

Comment: Apparently is stille the same in 2019 :(

Answer (score 1):

As of June 17th 2023 this is not possible in chromium based browsers. It's an issue ([453876](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=453876)) that is now known by the chrome team there is some recent activity on the ticket but it's been open for a pretty long time. Apparently something is up with the channel count of an audio stream in chromium itself ([1116042](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1116042)).

Answer (score -1):

It should work by calling getUserMedia four times, choosing a different device each time, and using createMediaStreamSource four times, although I haven't tested.

Comment: why choose a different device each time ?

Comment: You seem to be able to do this in FireFox, but in Chrome you can't choose a device. However, it doesn't help with the problem of using one single device with multiple inputs. Both browsers only see the first two channels of a multi-input interface.

Answer (score -1):

yes,you can list all  input devices and select one to use.

```
<html><body>

<select id="devices_list"></select>
<script>
function devices_list(){
        var handleMediaSourcesList = function(list){
            for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){
                var device= list[i];
                if(device.kind == 'audioinput') {
                    document.querySelector('#devices_list').options.add(new Option(device.label ,device.deviceId));
                }
            }

        }
        if (navigator["mediaDevices"] && navigator["mediaDevices"]["enumerateDevices"])
            {
                navigator["mediaDevices"]["enumerateDevices"]().then(handleMediaSourcesList);
            }
            // Old style API
            else if (window["MediaStreamTrack"] && window["MediaStreamTrack"]["getSources"])
            {
                window["MediaStreamTrack"]["getSources"](handleMediaSourcesList);
            }
}

function usemic(){

    navigator.getUserMedia ({
      "audio":{
            "optional": [{
            "sourceId": document.querySelector('#devices_list').value
             }]
        }}, function (stream) {
            //...some code to use stream from mic
        },function(err){
            debuginfo('getMedia ERR:'+err.message );
        });
}
</script>
</body></html>
```